# can't quit understand one step of the recurrence time complexity calculation

Tags: time-complexity, recursion

I solved the question T(n) = T(sqrt(n)) + 1 but can't quit understand one step of the solution[image]

I don't understand the transition in (1).
how did we conclude that T(m) = T(m/2) + 1 from the previous step that m is in the power?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It obviously is not correct. To fix it, define $S(m)=T(2^m)$, and then we would have $S(m)=S(m/2)+1$. Now, continue with the proof replacing everywhere $T(m)$ with $S(m)$. After you solve what $S(m)$ is, substitute $m=\log(n)$ in the solution to get what $T(n)=T(2^m)=S(m)$ is.

Comment: Thanks' a lot. got the answer. didn't pay attention to the substitution of the function as well.